# Mosfet H bridge - Is it correct?

Tags: arduino, h-bridge

I've designed this H bridge to control electromagnets using an arduino. I wanted to know if I've made it right, or there's something that can be improved.

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Update 1: Vcc is 12V and P1-P2 voltage will be arduino signal so 5V.
The thing is that I want to controll all four mosfets with only two signal ports.
Also I don't know that much of electronics.

This is the new design[image]

Thanks for your support

Comment: YOu should have gate resistors on the low side too.

Comment: What voltage is Vcc and what voltage is P1 and P2 when high?

Comment: Are you planning on using PWM on there solenoids? ANd are they pull-push type. If not a full bridge is not needed.

Comment: You have nice pulldowns and pull-ups on the gates, but because they are (cross-) connected, they will (in the basense of INP drive) nicely pull all FET gates to half-VCC, which is likely somethging you want to avoid.

Comment: Yup, as Dave mentions this does not work.. see this cross-post for a better method https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128127/mosfet-h-bridge-design?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This circuit will not work.

For every possible combination of control states, you will either short out your power supply, or no current at all will flow. In no case will any current flow through the load.